# How do you send a request directly to .DLL (not .ASPX, .ASHX, etc.)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, dll

I want to know how can we send direct request to .DLL with some parameters. I really don't want to use .ASPX and .ASHX. I hope this .DLL request is used for more secure site.

For example: IRCTC (India Railway site):

```
https://www.irctc.co.in/cgi-bin/bv60.dll/irctc/services/login.do
```

Please let me know how we can send or execute page from .DLL in ASP.NET.

Comment: If you dont want to use aspx or ashx, then what component on your server is instantiating the class (i assume) in your dll, so that something could be passed along ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by implementing the `IHttpHandler` interface and pretty much build your own routing from there (check the url and figure out what you should do and write the result using `context.Response`). Then register that in the web.config like this for IIS6 or lower:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="YOUR.TYPE, YOUR.ASSEMBLY"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Or like this for IIS7 or higher:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
    <add name="All" path="*" verb="*" type="YOUR.TYPE, YOUR.ASSEMBLY"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

However, this should not be any more secure then using the framework. What is your concern?

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid, there is no way to do that except remoting. But it is not a good idea, just use **.asmx** for that.

Comment: We can use .dll instead of (.aspx | .ashx | .asmx).. For example in windows xp, when we are going set folder icon mostly icons are comes from.dll file.. Like that! and  I want same in web site (not just for images). I am sure if we want to access the .dll resource in client side it will comes like this "/**WebResource.axd**?d=....". But anyway thanks for you answer.

Comment: -1: .asmx should not be used unless there's no other choice. WCF should be used instead.